# Working with Exceptions Exercise

Tags: java, beginner, exception

The task:

There is an `AccountManager` that makes transfers. It receives 2 arrays of the same size: accounts and sums. They need to be transferred to the accounts correspondingly.

```
public interface AccountManager {
    public boolean transfer(Account[] accounts, int[] deltas);
}
```

There is also an `Account` `interface`:

```
public interface Account {
    public void change(int delta) throws TryAgainException, BlockAccountException;
}
```

If `change()` throws `TryAgainException`, we just need to repeat the transfer operation. If `change()` throws `BlockAccountException`, we need to roll back the transfer operation. That is, reverse all changes to previous accounts.

**`AccountClass`**

```
public class AccountClass implements Account {

    // setting initial value to 100. so that account would not be empty
    private int accountNum;
    private int currentAccount = 100;

    public AccountClass(int accountNum) {
        this.accountNum = accountNum;
    }

    @Override
    public void change(int delta) throws TryAgainException,
            BlockAccountException {
        System.out.println("account before change" + toString());

        int newBalance = getCurrentAccount() + delta;
        if (newBalance < 0) {
            throw new BlockAccountException(
                    "money cannot be withdrawn as balance will be negative");
        } else if (delta == 100) {
            throw new TryAgainException();
        }
        setCurrentAccount(getCurrentAccount() + delta);

        System.out.println("account after change" + toString());
    }

    public int getCurrentAccount() {
        return currentAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account" + accountNum + " [currentAccount=" + currentAccount + "]";
    }

    // making setter private so it will be impossible to modify account from
    // outside
    private void setCurrentAccount(int currentAccount) {
        this.currentAccount = currentAccount;
    }
```

AccountManagerClass

```
public class AccountManagerClass implements AccountManager {

    @Override
    public boolean transfer(Account[] accounts, int[] deltas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            int tryNum = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    accounts[i].change(deltas[i]);
                    break;
                } catch (TryAgainException e) {
                    tryNum++;
                    if (tryNum == 5) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("trying again");
                } catch (BlockAccountException e) {
                    // rollback
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("rolling back");
                    if (i > 0) {
                        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                            try {
                                accounts[j].change(-deltas[j]);
                            } catch (TryAgainException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (BlockAccountException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**`Main`**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AccountManagerClass accountManagerClass = new AccountManagerClass();
        Account[] accounts = {new AccountClass(1), new AccountClass(2), new AccountClass(3), new AccountClass(4)};
        int[] deltas = {100, 200, -200, 99};
        accountManagerClass.transfer(accounts, deltas);
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually its the responsibility of a database transaction. Can you use database transactions?

Comment: Is concurrency a requirement, or just something nice to consider in your codebase?

Comment: It's *extremely weird* to fix a starting account balance to 100, unless this is part of an exercise and indicated as such... we're not in *Monopoly* here...

Comment: sorry, i should've mention, yes it is an exercise not a real case

Answer (score 2):

```
// making setter private so it will be impossible to modify account from
// outside
private void setCurrentAccount(int currentAccount) {
    this.currentAccount = currentAccount;
}
```

So, what's the point of this setter at all? :)